# Is it possible to git push --force in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

From within Visual Studio Code, is it possible to do a `git push --force <repo> <branch>` in some way?

Answer (score 119):

Since 1.35 (May 2019), provided that `Settings > Extensions > Git > Allow Force Push` is set, the force push option is also visible in the Git menu (three dots, more actions), sub-menu "`Pull, Push`".

You must first enable it in settings:

[image: settings]

## [image: Git Menu]

[image: Force push now visible]

**Note**: You needed, with 1.35, to restart VSCode (or at least "Reload (VSCode) windows") in order to see that new option.
With more recent version of VSCode (1.65, 2022), no need to reload/restart.

See [issue 62020](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/62020), closed with [PR 62021](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/62021).

As noted by [CletusW](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1431146/cletusw) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42635701/is-it-possible-to-git-push-force-in-vscode/56485045#comment110023831_56485045):

> Note also by default this uses the safer `--force-with-lease` option, also configurable in `Settings > Extensions > Git`, toward the bottom

I detailed `--force-with-lease` in "[`git push --force-with-lease` vs. `--force`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52937476/6309)".

---

Since [VSCode 1.84](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_84#_source-control), Oct. 2023:

> ### Force push using `--force-if-includes`
>
> This milestone there is now support for the `--force-if-includes` option, which is an auxiliary option to `--force-with-lease` added in Git 2.30.
>
> The new option ensures that commits that are being force-pushed were created after examining the commit at the tip of the remote reference, and reduces the chance of losing commits when auto fetch is enabled.
>
> You can disable the use of `--force-if-includes` by disabling the `git.useForcePushIfIncludes` setting.

See "[Is `git push --force-with-lease` always safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64627761/6309)" for more on the [`--force-if-includes`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt---no-force-if-includes) option.

Comment: Note also by default this uses the safer --force-with-lease option, also configurable in Settings > Extensions > Git, toward the bottom.

Comment: @CletusW THank you, good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: I restarted vscode but still this option is not there.
Edit - It was present in Pull, Push sub-menu.

Comment: @MayankKataria It is not in mine either... because I did not activate first the setting "`Allow Force Push`": activate it, and you will see this option.

Comment: @VonC Yes I got it. Its not present in main menu now. We have to navigate to sub menu of 'Pull, Push' option.

Comment: @MayankKataria I have edited the answer and updated the picture, showing the option in its current place as you mentioned. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: Do they have something similar for force fetch?

Comment: @Trass3r I do not think so, it is more an option in the [refspec used](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec)

Answer (score 25):

It is now available after September 2018 v1.28 release.
Check the release notes for more information:
https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_28#_push-force

[image]

**EDIT:** Thank [@Kevin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/244702/kevin-robatel) for the hint.
If you can't find the option, you can change the VSCode settings as follows:

[image]

Comment: If you don't find this option: Settings > Extensions > Git > Allow Force Push

Answer (score 7):

I also faced same issue where I couldn't find the option to do force push in `vscode 1.40`

Here is a screenshot to find the option in the setting

[image]

Comment: this is the same with adding  `"git.allowForcePush": true,` to `setting.json`

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Visual Studio Code
2. Go to File --> Open Folder and select your project folder
3. Select Ctrl+` to open the terminal window
4. Type `git push --force <repo> <branch>` in terminal window and hot enter

Comment: this actually helped me while other answer (even from other questions) didn't