# What is the difference between VS Code's 'Commit (Amend)' and 'Commit (Signed Off)'?

Tags: git, version-control, visual-studio-code

A picture where these buttons are

[image]

Hi I started to use VS Code version control.

I know difference between 'Commit All' and 'Commit Staged'

but can't figure out  commit (Amend) and commit (Signed Off)

I checked VS Code version control Doc and it is not explained ...

I want to know what are they and when to use it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Those are not VS Code features but just Git commit options.

**Signed Off**: adding a Signed-off-by line at the end of the commit log message.

Ref: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#Documentation/git-commit.txt---signoff

**Amend**: really *amend* that already committed on current branch.

Ref: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#Documentation/git-commit.txt---amend

Comment: I get merge conflicts whenever I use the amend option from VSCode?

Comment: @mspoulsen You have to force push whenever you git amend (or rewrite git history in general); settings to enable in VSCode: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56485045/8214747

Comment: @SaeedBaig I amended my most recent commit just a moment ago and did not have to force push, maybe because it's at the HEAD of a branch and not pushed? What conditions require force push for amending commits?